# How to select a Subset of PolySet data in R?

Tags: r

I am using the `PBSmapping` package in R to model data from [diva-gis](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata). I can read in the shapefiles and plot them with no issue.

```
library(PBSmapping)
df = importShapefile("/path/df.shp")
plotPolys(df)
```

But the problem is I can't figure out how to subset the PolySet data. For example, for Bhutan's administrative areas file, runnning `str(df)` shows:

```
Classes ‘PolySet’ and 'data.frame': 59294 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ PID: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ SID: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ POS: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ X  : num  91 91 91 91 91 ...
 $ Y  : num  27.2 27.2 27.2 27.2 27.2 ...
 - attr(*, "PolyData")=Classes ‘PolyData’ and 'data.frame': 201 obs. of  19 variables:
  ..$ PID       : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ ID_0      : int  35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 ...
  ..$ ISO       : Factor w/ 1 level "BTN": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ NAME_0    : Factor w/ 1 level "Bhutan": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ ID_1      : int  486 486 486 486 486 486 486 486 472 472 ...
  ..$ NAME_1    : Factor w/ 20 levels "Bumthang","Chhukha",..: 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 1 1 ...
  ..$ ID_2      : int  9280 9281 9282 9283 9284 9285 9286 9287 9141 9142 ...
  ..$ NAME_2    : Factor w/ 201 levels "Aemeri","Athang",..: 8 19 73 126 129 138 163 186 4 29 ...
  ..$ VARNAME_2 : Factor w/ 0 levels: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ NL_NAME_2 : Factor w/ 0 levels: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ HASC_2    : Factor w/ 0 levels: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ CC_2      : Factor w/ 0 levels: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ TYPE_2    : Factor w/ 1 level "Unknown": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ ENGTYPE_2 : Factor w/ 1 level "Unknown": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ VALIDFR_2 : Factor w/ 1 level "Unknown": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ VALIDTO_2 : Factor w/ 1 level "Unknown": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ REMARKS_2 : Factor w/ 1 level "Second level is probably 3rd level": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ Shape_Leng: num  0.82 0.706 0.433 1.053 0.751 ...
  ..$ Shape_Area: num  0.01852 0.01736 0.00877 0.04298 0.01871 ...
 - attr(*, "parent.child")= num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "shpType")= int 5
 - attr(*, "prj")= chr "GEOGCS[\"GCS_WGS_1984\",DATUM[\"D_WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS_1984\",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"D"| __truncated__
 - attr(*, "projection")= chr "LL"
```

How can I subset out PolySet data where "Name_1" is "Bumthang"? Incidentally, in `maptools`, this can be done by:

```
library(maptools)
df = readShapeSpatial("/path/df.shp")
df.data = as.data.frame(df) #For understanding the data structure
df.Bumthang = admin.mpt[as.character(admin.mpt$NAME_1)=='Bumthang',]
```

Comment: I can't get the code to run... can you post some straightforward instructions on how to get "Bhutan's administrative area" so I can duplicate your "df" ?

Comment: Sure. Go to: http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata, and select "Bhutan" (or any other country) and "Administrative Areas" and hit "OK". The next page will show a map of Bhutan, with a red "Download" link at the bottom. This will download the "BTN_adm.zip" file. You can use the "BTN_adm2.shp" file in there.

Comment: Does it have have to be a Polyset? Won't it be easier to subset it first via some other module, write to file, and then plot the resulting subset via PBSmapping?

Answer (score 5):

What about using a using another library to subset the file? You could subset the data using rgdal, save to file, import the shapefile containing the subset and plot it using PBSMapping.

```
library(rgdal)
library(PBSmapping)

df <-  readOGR(".","df")
subset <- df[df$NAME_1=="Bumthang",]
writeOGR(subset, ".", "bumthang", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
bum = importShapefile("bumthang.shp")
plotPolys(bum, projection=TRUE)
```

[image]

Or you could do away with PBSmapping altogether.

```
 plot(subset, axes=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying to find something within PBSmapping. One alternative is to use PolySet2SpatialPolygons in the maptools library, and then subset it. Youre rgdal pointer is nice. Many thanks, R.K.

Comment: It's just that using the PolySet can be slow. I've tried it on my machine for comparison and computer froze for a moment when I tried the PBSmapping solution.